# Server returned HTTP response code: 500 while posting FormData using java

Tags: java

I am trying to post formData in java. I am getting 500 server error. In the API I am trying to call the name of the FormData parameter is template @FormDataParam("template")

Here I have shared my code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
byte[] data = formData.getBytes();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
BufferedReader readData;
try ( DataOutputStream writeData =
            new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {

    writeData.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
        + "template" + "\""+ "\\r\\n");
    writeData.write(data);
    writeData.flush();
    readData = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = readData.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a server error, ie. the problem is on the server side, not client side.

Comment: have you checked the path? what exactly does the error message say? does it reach the back-end? ...?

Comment: yes, the data I am trying to send is available.Seems I have missed something in setting form data parameter name.

Comment: Hi Sasi,
The problem is not in the server bcoz while i am trying with ajax to call the same server it is working fine.

Comment: @kayal This may not be the cause of the error, but you should probably close your writeData stream before reading the response (rather than just flushing it.) Since you've used a try with resources block, you can just move your code to read the data outside of this block, and then it'll do the close for you.